# keytool error: java.io.IOException: Illegal header: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Tags: linux, keytool

Using the following command:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55.x86_64/bin/keytool -import -alias tomcat -trustcacerts -file certificate.crt -keystore $OBM_HOMEconf/keystore
```

I receive the error:

```
keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.io.IOException: Illegal header: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

I generated the certificate on GoDaddy, as I had done previously for the server I'm trying to install this cert on, and downloaded the Tomcat version of the files from them.

I ensured all of the hyphens are actual hyphens (I've had an issue before where they came out as em dashes) in both the cert and the command.  I do not understand why it is saying that the cert header is an illegal header.

Comment: Trailing space in header line?

Comment: @Omikron No, I've removed all of the trailing spaces completely and cleaned the line endings.

Comment: @Omikron I spoke too soon.  Evidently it did indeed add an extra white space at the end of every line when I pasted the cert into a file through the command line.  This was my issue.  Go ahead and make that an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java's PEM parser is a bit finicky when it comes to extra whitespace. A trailing space character in the header line causes this error message.